# R equivalent of Matlab trisurf()

Tags: r

I have three vectors x, y, U that I would like to plot as a surface. I can do this in Matlab using functions delaunay() and trisurf(). However, I would like to do the same in R but can't find something similar.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`persp`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/persp.html).

Comment: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e12/help/10/11/4035.html

Comment: Unfortunately, persp() requires x and y to be increasing vectors. My vectors are not and only either x or y can be ordered.

Comment: You may want to embed your `x` and `y` vectors in a regular field. Or look at `rgl::plot3d` and `grDevices::xyz.coords`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `geometry` package for `delaunayn` and `surf.tri`, and these can be plotted with `rgl.triangles` from `rgl`.

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/geometry/docs/surf.tri

I used this recently here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90635/what-programs-would-allow-for-the-mapping-of-a-geoid-in-3d/90763#90763

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked first time and gave exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do trisurf with Plotly's open-source R client. R code here:

http://moderndata.plot.ly/trisurf-plots-in-r-using-plotly/
[image: trisurf in R]

Comment: Thanks very much for this comment. The package plot_ly is very impressive, with many great plotting facilities. By the way, I tried the Moebius example which worked fine. However, with type="surface", it did not appear able to render the image.